# WebRTC in Firefox and Opera on Android. Usability issues

Tags: html, firefox, constraints, webrtc, opera

I'm having WebRTC  usability issue in Opera (55.0.2719.50560) and Firefox (68.3.0) on Android (Samsung Galaxy S6).

Firefox problem: is asking me multiple (around 3) times about permission to use camera. Also is asking me all the time which camera I want to use (regardless that constrains are set)

Opera: is asking me multiple times (around 3) which camera I want to use (regardless of constraints).

Exactly the same code is working properly on the same phone on Chrome and using Safari and Chrome on iPhone.
All content is served using https.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Show us the code with the problem

Comment: Use `{exact}` constraints.